# angular js http post not writing to file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my app

```
objectsApp.controller('ObjectsController', ['$http', '$scope', '$routeParams', 
function($http, $scope, $routeParams) {
        $http.post('1object.json', "my first write").then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
}]);
```

When run, this is the response (data)

```
Object {data: "", status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

However, there is no change to the file `1object.json` (expected `my first write`)

The file 1object.json exists, but is just blank. I am running on a windows machine.

Why wouldn't this be writing?

Comment: `POST`ing to a static file does not automatically write to it.  It depends on what your server is doing with the request.  You would have to take the post body and write to that file explicitly.

Comment: @ExplosionPills That's what I assumed originally, angular being client-side, but a couple tutorials on the web recommend the above method

Comment: @ColinPalmer Just curious can you post a link to one of said tutorials?

Comment: Something either misinterpreted or faulty from those tutorials. `.json` files are static files with no dynamic language code processing. Have to use a server script in whatever language it is running to write to file ... and will find it simpler in the long run to use alternate storage like db than trying to index your own json files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Node.js you can use the [fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to get the functionality you want.
In your server.js you would have a route which your angular `$http.post` directs to, and that route would use `fs.writeFile` and the posted data to write the .json file.

EDIT: I would like to mention, depending on what your use for the JSON file is, you may consider using a database like redis to store your JSON data.